# finding character in string C language

Tags: c

I am searching a character at first occurence in string using the following code. 
But it is taking some time when the character is too long or the character that I am 
searching is at far extent, which delays other operations. How could I tackle this problem. The code is below here.

Note: `attrPtr` is a `char *` which holds a reference to a string containing `'"'` character at far extent.

```
int position = 0;

char qolon = '"';//character to search

while (*(attrPtr + position++) != qolon);

char* attrValue = NULL;

attrValue = (char*)malloc(position * sizeof(char));

strncpy(attrValue, attrPtr, position-1);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) will usually be somewhat faster.  Also, you need to check for the NUL terminator, which strchr will handle for you.

```
char *quotPtr = strchr(attrPtr, qolon);
if(quotPtr == NULL)
{
  ... // Handle error
}
int position = quotPtr - attrPtr;
char* attrValue = (char*) malloc((position + 1) * sizeof(char));
memcpy(attrValue, attrPtr, position);
attrValue[position] = '\0';
```

I haven't tested, though.

EDIT: Fix off-by-one.

Comment: `NUL` is the ASCII moniker, the C standard uses the term 'null character`.

Comment: There's no point in using `strncpy()` since you already know the exact number of characters to copy - you might as well use `memcpy()`, which should be more efficient.

Comment: There's no need to cast malloc(). sizeof(char) is always 1.

Answer (score 8):

C has a built-in function for searching for a character in a string - `strchr()`.  `strchr()` returns a pointer to the found character, not the array position, so you have to subtract the pointer to the start of the string from the returned pointer to get that.  You could rewrite your function as:

```
char qolon = '"';//character to search
char *found;
char *attrVal = NULL;

found = strchr(attrPtr, qolon);

if (found)
{
    size_t len = found - attrPtr;

    attrVal = malloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(attrVal, attrPtr, len);
    attrVal[len] = '\0';
}
```

This may be faster than your original by a small constant factor; however, you aren't going to get an order-of-magnitude speedup.  Searching for a character within an un-ordered string is fundamentally O(n) in the length of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Two important things:

1) Always check for a NULL terminator when searching a string this way:

```
while (*(attrPtr + position++) != qolon);
```

should be:

```
while (attrPtr[position] && attrPtr[position++] != qolon);
```

(if passed a string lacking your searched character, it could take a very long time as it scans all memory). Edit: I just noticed someone else posted this before, me, but oh well. I disagree, btw, strchr() is fine, but a simple loop that also checks for the terminator is fine (and often has advantages), too.

2) BEWARE of strncpy()!

```
strncpy(attrValue, attrPtr, position-1);
```

strlen(attrPtr)>=(position-1) so this will **NOT** null terminate the string in attrValue, which could cause all kinds of problems (including incredible slowdown in code later on). As a related note, strncpy() is erm, uniquely designed, so if you do something like:

```
char buf[512];
strncpy(buf,"",4096);
```

You will be writing 4096 bytes of zeroes.

Personally, I use lstrcpyn() on Win32, and on other platforms I have a simple implementation of it. It is much more useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

It requires an `O(n)` algorithm to search for a character in the string. So you can't do much better than what your are already doing. Also, note that you are missing `memset(attrValue, 0, position);` , otherwise your string `attrValue` will not be null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you posted doesn't properly handle the case where the character doesn't exist in the string. If that happens, it will just merilly march through memory until it either randomly happens to find a byte that matches your char, or you blow past your allocated memory and get a segfault. I suspect that is why it seems to be "taking too long" sometimes.

In C, strings are usually terminated with a 0 (ascii nul, or `'\0'`). Alternatively, if you know the length of the string ahead of time, you can use that.

Of course, there is a standard C library routine that does exactly this: `strchr()`. A wise programmer would use that rather than risk bugs by rolling their own.