# identifying char ' in C

Tags: c, cs50

I'm probably implementing this code in a terrible way, but i'm currently doing CS50 and trying to search my string for the char '. I searched for other chars such as `text [i] == '!'` however when doing `text [i] == '''` it doesn't work correctly. Is it possible to make it work in this way?

Here's my terrible code if your interested... i'm trying to find the number of letters, words, and sentences.. it works other than the characters i can't define.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
string text = get_string("Input text: "); //accept text input
int i;
int length = strlen(text);
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;
int count3 = 0;
int excludeothers = (length - count);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if(text[i] == ' ' || text [i] == '!' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '.' || text[i] == ',' || text[i] == '"' || text[i] == ':' || text[i] == ';' || text[i] == '-' || text[i] == ''') //check number of letters
    {
        count++;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)
{
    if((text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '\0') && (text[i-1] != ' ' || text[i-1] != '\0')) //check number of words
    {
        count2++;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if((text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text [i] == '!') && (text[i+1] == ' ' || text[i+1] == '\0')) //check number of sentences
    {
        count3++;
    }
}


    printf("%i letters\n", excludeothers); //print letters
    printf("%i words\n", count2); //print words
    printf("%i sentences\n", count3); //print sentences

}
```

Comment: `int excludeothers = (length - count);` is in the wrong place , it needs to be after you work out the value of `count` . This statement doesn't set up a formula,  it performs an immediate computation

Comment: you may want to look into the `ispunct` and `isalpha` etc. function family from `#include <ctype.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it:

```
'\''
```

This means the single quote char. Same way you can have double quote in a string: `"\""`

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Comment: Thank you! figured it was something simple. Appreciate the help! was having trouble articulating the question which made it hard to google!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it your way, then, yes, you need to escape that character. Take a look at [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/escape-sequences-c/) article about escaping characters in general. It will help you knowing which ones can be passed as normal characters and which ones will need a backslash in front of them.

However, if you are considering other options, take a look at `strchr()`. It is a builtin function that you can use. Using this will drastically improve and simplify your code. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963394/finding-character-in-string-c-language) question discussion for more information. And here is a reference for [C documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) on this function.

Comment: `strchr` still requires escaping the single quote.